# How to access private method in trait

Tags: groovy

I would like to access private methods in a trait for unit testing purposes, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have the following test code:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    private String yell() { "YAAAH!" }          
}

SomeTrait traitInstance = new Object() as SomeTrait
println traitInstance.yell()
```

What I'm trying to achieve in this this example is to access the private method and print out "YAAAH!", but instead I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Object15_groovyProxy.yell() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: sleep(long), sleep(long, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), every(), find(), dump() at ConsoleScript24.run(ConsoleScript24:7)
```

What can I do to access the private method?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, [as the documentation says](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_private_methods):

> Traits may also define private methods. Those methods will not appear in the trait contract interface:

You should be able to call them from other, public trait methods, or static method in the trait, eg:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    private String yell() { "YAAAH!" }          
    String doYell() { yell() }
}

SomeTrait traitInstance = new Object() as SomeTrait
println traitInstance.doYell()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to call the private method without changing the trait, by letting a class implement it and then call it:

```
trait YellTrait {
    private String yell() { "YAAAH!" }          
}

class SomeClass implements YellTrait {
}

println new SomeClass().yell()
```

Conceivably, you could let your unit test class implement the trait and then call the private method directly.

Comment: and how is this not the very same what @tim_yates answered?

Comment: I think it is a lot nicer not to have to change the trait you want to unit test, to call the private method. The test-specific code should be in the test class, not the implementation.

Comment: sorry, to less coffee.  but this now makes me wonder: why on earth do you want to test a private method?

Comment: I find that with some private methods you can get better test coverage faster if you test them directly. They might have errors that are never exposed by the current calling method, and when you work in 5-8 man teams where you expect people to be able to change and extend code others have written, it is important that even the private methods do what their name claim they do, and not just what they are used for currently. But I see your point and most private methods I don't unit test.

Comment: @Svante quite frankly, the urge to test private methods indicates a Large Class code smell. Better split the code into several classes and compose the original behavior from their (now) public methods.